# Laravel relationships confusion

Tags: php, database, laravel, reference

I'm learning Laravel these days and want to create some tables, models, and stuff.

I have companies, jobs, and employees. If I understood correctly, public functions in model files are fields:

```
 public function jobs()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Job');
  }
```

Does this mean that I can create another function for `currentJob` like this:

```
 public function currentJob()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Job');
  }
```

Also, do I need to add `belongsTo` for each relationship? For example, in the user model?

Comment: if you want to get user against any job then you need to add `belongsTo` relationship in user model

Comment: @merko Check out the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: actually Laravel can't help you if you don't understand fundamental of database relationship, you should learn that first.

Answer (score 2):

Try to see it in `English` than in `PHP`, this way you will be able to use right functions in right places.

So you have 3 tables: companies, jobs, and employees

Now before you dig in with Model in Laravel, you need to know what are the relationships among those three tables.

I assume the relationship between companies and jobs is one to many which means one company can have many jobs.

The relationship between jobs and employees is one to one because one job can be assigned to one employee.

Now based upon your project, these relationships might be different but the first step is to establish the relationships among three tables.

Now, assuming that you do have the same relationships as I explained above, your Models will have the following "public" functions:

```
//Company Model

//this function will returns all the jobs associated with the specific company_id
public function jobs()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Job');
}
```

========

```
//Job Model

//this function will return the employee associated with the specific job_id
public function employee()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Employee');
}

//now you can also have a function to fetch the company to which the job "belongs to", this is a reverse case which means, the jobs table has "company_id"

public function company()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
}
```

And same you can do in employee model because each employee belongs to a job means has a job_id so you will use belongsTo relationship:

```
//Employee Model

    //now you can also have a function to fetch the job to which the employee "belongs to", this is a reverse case which means, the employees table has "job_id"

    public function job()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Job');
    }
```

One thing to note that hasOne and belongsTo are the functions which are the counterpart of each other.

So if Job model uses hasOne for Employee, Employee will use belongsTo for Job, considering the employees table has "job_id" as a foreign key. It just matters that which Model you are using, based upon that you can get details of another model using these functions.

For more details, of course, refer to [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships).
*I hope it helps clear your confusion*

Comment: Can I have multiple fields, like `currentJob` and `previousJobs`, both referenced to job model?

Comment: think what would `currentJob` and `previousJobs` return? what do you want to achieve by that?

Comment: I want a current job separated from previous ones. Also, how would I use the job model just as a reference, I don't want to pass company id there, I tried it but it's looking for company id.

Comment: You can't have a relationship without having foreign_key, that is basic Database understanding. You can make whatever function you like in any model and make it do whatever you want but that will not come under the category of Laravel relationship question so please ask it separate. A question where you clearly state your objective and what have you tried to achieve it otherwise people will confuse your post with laravel relationship misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

For basic model relationships :

```
// Job Model

public function employee(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');

}

// Employee Model
public function jobs(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\Job');
}
```

If you want to get current job, you can add an [appended property](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) :

```
// Employee Model

protected $appends = ['current_job'];

//Then create function for  the same : 

public function getCurrentJob()
{
  return $this->jobs()->latest()->first();
}
```

Comment: This answer got an upvote which is strange because, its showing to return App\Job from Job model when name of the function is employee so basically when you will call employee() from controller, it will return jobs? :) same goes with job() function and it makes sense to you guys? to me its like more confusing and incorrect, still not downvoting :) maybe others know better

Comment: You corrected your answer, good job, the least you could do is say thanks :)

Comment: Thanks man my bad, I corrected it from mobile as soon s I realised I messed up when writing it

Comment: its ok..no problem :)